# How to load rvm with correct gemset then execute a rake task

Tags: ruby, bash, scripting, rvm

Writing a script that cds into another dir, loads the correct rvm rvmrc file, then allows me to execute a rake task.

I have the below script working on my computer, but when others pull it down to their machine they get the following error "Ruby rvmrc is not installed".

```
Bundler.with_clean_env do
  Dir.chdir("../some_dir") do
    puts `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm && rvm --with-rubies rvmrc exec -- rake some_task`
  end
end
```

I have the most up to date version of rvm (so do they) and I'm on mt.lion

I have tried creating a bash function like so...

```
function foo {
  [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" && rvm use @my_gemset
}
```

Or, replacing this line

```
rvm --with-rubies rvmrc exec
```

with things like...

```
rvm rvmrc load
rvm use <gemset>
rvm env --path -- ree-1.8.7@some_gemset
```

But none of it has worked.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work:

```
~/.rvm/bin/rvm rvmrc trust ../some_dir
~/.rvm/bin/rvm in ../some_dir do rake some_task
```

Comment: I ended up just establishing another ActiveRecord connection within the app and manipulating the models directly.  But, the above did work if I were to keep with the shelling out approach.