# Switching directories under rake task fails to load new directory's gemset

Tags: bash, rake, rvm

Within the context of a rake task, I am attempting to `cd` into a sibling project directory from which I would like to invoke a rake task specific to that project. However, it seems that the gemset for the latter directory is not loaded. The directory structure from a top level looks like this:

```
2.2.1@DirOne
    - 2.2.1 Gems ...
2.2.3@DirTwo
    - 2.2.3 Gems ...
```

When running under the context of project in `DirOne`, the rake attempts to `cd` into `DirTwo` to execute a rake task specific to the project within `DirTwo`. However, rake aborts in the second rake task as it complains that it hits the following error:

> LoadError: cannot load such file -- ci/reporter/rake/rspec

In the error, `ci/reporter/rake/rspec` is a gem that belongs under `2.2.3@DirTwo`. Might there be a way to execute the following in the context of `DirOne` in a rake task?

`cd ../DirTwo && rvm use 2.2.3@DirTwo && rake something_specific_to_DirTwo`

---

**What I've tried**

Using `IO.popen(source ./script_to_run_the_above.sh)`, and `IO.popen(#{above_command} 2>&1` to dump the output. I also tried using `FileUtils.cd` to create a block to execute the above script within the context of the `cd` filepath, but all of it either does nothing (no error), or throws the `LoadError`.

Comment: This may be useful to you https://stackoverflow.com/a/12475787/3674262